# how to take n number of input from user in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Is the below code correct for taking n number of input from user.

```
take_input(0):- !.
take_input(Num):-
writeln('enter course code '),
read(Crs),
/* some code */
Num is Num - 1,
take_input(Num).
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `.` after the `!` but otherwise it doesn't look insane. Did you try running it? In general, running code to find out if it works is probably easier than posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can't do `Num is Num - 1`. In Prolog and have it perform as you expect like other languages. That's saying you have a `Num` which can have the same value as `Num - 1` which will always fail.

Comment: @lurker. It runs but takes user input only once, since you said it would never work. So what is the workaround to decrement the counter, if this is not possible ? Or any other way of taking n number of user input

Comment: There's no modifying variables in Prolog. You would say `Num0 is Num - 1, take_input(Num0)` instead (or `succ(Num0, Num)`, which works both ways). (I should have caught this, @lurker!)

Comment: @Far my point is that the statement `Num is Num - 1` will always file, not the entire predicate. That failure is why you see the results you are seeing, which is that it will not continue to ask for more user input.